# ArcMap Python Question: Trying to Field Calculate Slope Percent in to Text

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, field-calculator

I have a layer of polygons that I spatially joined to a raster to point layer of slope percents. My polygons now have the percent of slope in a field called Avg_point. I want to use the field calculator to take that percent number (something like 22.345 or 56.45 etc.) and turn it into a text in the "slope" field (that was already in the layer of polygons) and I want that text to say something likes "Steep (>25%)"

So I wrote a script

```
SLOPE=slopecorrect(!SLOPE!, !Avg_grid_code!)
```

PreLogic:

```
def slopecorrect(slope, avg):
    if avg > 25: 
       return Steep
```

I am getting no errors but my "slope" field just fills in  I have tried other things but I can't seem to get it to fill in that field

I have looked around a bit and thought this thread was helpful but its still not producing results
[ArcMap Calculate Field..if "text" in !Field!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91585/arcmap-calculate-field-if-text-in-field)

Comment: For code formatting easiest is to paste block in from your text editor, select the block, and use `Ctrl-K` to apply (will indent properly etc., most of the time).

Comment: you need to quote your return, in order to make it a string, `return "Steep"`

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help everyone. I can't believe it was  that easy1 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def slope_correct(slope, avg):
    if avg > 25:
        return "holly crap"
    elif 0 < avg <= 25:
        return "easy peasy"
    else:
        return "unknown"
```